# How to set the value of an extra field in the list view?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I added an extra field `clan` to the `ModelView` of the class `Matriline` and add it to the columns in list view, as shown below.

How can I set the value of the extra field `clan` in the list view?

**views.py**

```
class MatrilineAdmin(sqla.ModelView):

    form_extra_fields = {
        'clan': SelectField('Clan',
            coerce=int,
            choices=[ (c.id, c.name) for c in Clan.query.all()])
    }
    create_template = 'admin/create.html'
    edit_template = 'admin/edit.html'
    column_list = ('name', 'pod', 'clan')
```

**models.py**

```
class Matriline(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'matriline'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    calls = db.relationship('Call', backref='matriline', lazy='select')
    pod_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pod.id'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Pod(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pod'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    matrilines = db.relationship('Matriline', backref='pod', lazy='select')
    clan_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clan.id'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Clan(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clan'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    pods = db.relationship('Pod', backref='clan', lazy='select')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code in [BaseModelView.index_view](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/flask_admin/model/base/#BaseModelView.index_view) there is no "configuration" option for that. You will need to override the `get_list` method in your `MatrilineAdmin`-class.

This would look something like:

```
class MadrilineAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    def get_list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        count, data = super().get_list(*args, **kwargs)
        for d in data:
            d.clan = 'whatever you want'
        return count, data
```

---

You could also try to specify a [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) from Matriline to Clan and to define the clan property directly in the model class:

```
class Matriline(db.Model):
    # …
    pod = db.relationship('Pod')

    @property
    def clan(self):
        if not self.pod:
            return None
        return self.pod.clan

class Pod(db.Model):
    # …
    clan = db.relationship('Clan')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class ExampleDatabase(sqla.ModelView):

    def _list_name(self, context, model, name):
        return 'something you like'

    column_formatters = {
        'example': _list_name
    }

    def get_column_names(self, only_columns, excluded_columns):
        only_columns.append('example')
        return super().get_column_names(only_columns, excluded_columns)
```

Works for me.